# Starting new activity on navigation drawer item click

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make a navigation drawer that opens a new activity when the user taps an item.

There is 5 items in my drawer and I want each of them to open a different activity.

I don't know how to do this?

My code is the following

```
public class TabView extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_view);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item ) {
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){

        }
        return true;
    }

    private void setupViewPager( ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Charts");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Weather");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Checklists");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [example](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        ...
    }
}
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
private void selectItem(int position) {
    //menu items position as it appears in listview
    Switch(position){
        case 0 :
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 1 :
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityThree.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        //more case for you menu item
        default :
            //start default activity here
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have missed something, checkout syntax [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), plz share your code where you are getting this error.

Comment: yep everything seems fine @Fahadsk . this is the code where i get the error

Comment: private void selectItem(int position) {
         Switch(position){
            case 0 :
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case 1 :
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityThree.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            //more case for you menu item
            default :
                //start default activity here
                break;
        }
    }